# Not getting the results from the suggestions trying to subset data

Tags: sas, format

```
DATA proj4.gasQTR;
   SET proj4.gasQTR;
   INPUT Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4;
   IF MONTH = 1 or 2 or 3 THEN Q1 = 1;
   ELSE IF MONTH = 4 or 5 or 6 THEN  Q2 = 2;
   ELSE IF MONTH = 7 or 8 or 9 THEN Q3 = 3;
   ELSE IF MONTH = 10 or 11 or 12 THEN Q4 = 4;   
   quarter = MONTH; FORMAT Quarter qtrw.;
RUN;
```

I am trying to get a 1-4 value for each qtr of each year, my error comes from Quarter qtrw. 'ERROR 388-185 Expecting an arithmetic operator'
*Data is already in 1-4 format for the month variable

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally do not use both a SET statement to retrieve data from an existing dataset and an INPUT statement to read values from a text file in the same data step.  And if you do want to INPUT values from a text file you must tell SAS where to find the text by including either an INFILE statement or add the text in-line with the code by using a DATALINES (or CARDS) statement.

SAS will consider any number that is not zero or missing as TRUE.  So the condition `2 or 3 or 4` is always TRUE.  So Q1 will always be set to 1 and Q2, Q3 and Q4 will always be missing (or if they existed already unchanged).  If you want to test if a variables has any of a number of values use the IN operator instead of the equality operator. `month in (1 2 3 4)`

You also should not be reading and writing the same dataset.  If there are logic issues in your coding you might destroy the original dataset.  So hopefully you have backup copy of proj4.gasQTR, or a program that can recreate it.

What is the format QTRW ?  Is that something you created? Show its definition.

Assuming you have a variable named MONTH with integer values in the range 1 to 12 you can calculate QUARTER with integer values in the range 1 to 4 with a simple arithmetic function instead of coding a series of IF conditions.

```
data want;
  set have;
  quarter = ceil(month/3) ;
run;
```

If you actually have a DATE variable then perhaps all you were supposed to do was use the MONTH or QTR format to display the dates as the month number or quarter number that they fall into.

Try this program to see the impact of applying different formats to the same values.

```
data test;
  do month=1 to 12;
    date1=mdy(month,1,2022);
    date2=date1;
    date3=date1;
    output;
  end;
  format date1 date9. date2 month. date3 qtr.;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got QTRw from SAS Doc community page and I was also very confused by it as I had not heard it before. Someone was asking a similar question and I thought I could try it.  Also - as they are dubbed a "super user" I thought it was a reliable source.  This was there answer:

Comment: *Their answer - 'For a very large number of purposes you may not even need to create an additional variable at all. SAS provides several formats for date values that will display quarters: QTRw. by default displays 1 to 4, QTRRw. which displays quarter as Roman numerals: I II III and IV, YYQw which will show year and quarter information together depending on width YYQ. default shows YYYYQn such as 2018Q1 or YYQxw. where you choose a charcter for x that controls the separator between the year and quarter numbe allowing such things as 2012/3 or 2017-2.'

Comment: You can use the QTR format with DATE values.  DATE values will not by from 1 to 12 like your code is attempting to test for (unless they are dates in the first two weeks on 1960).  The `w` is the way the documentation shows that you can include Width number when making an actual format specification.  Since QTR will print just a single digit the default width is 1.  So use `qtr.` or `qtr1.` in the format statement.

Comment: It keeps asking for datalines.  As QTRw is supposed to be default I ended the code with format;

Comment: Did you remove the INPUT statement or not?  That is what would require either on INFILE statement or DATALINES.  If you have an existing dataset you are pulling in with SET there is no reason to include an INPUT statement at all.

Comment: It keeps asking for datalines.  As QTRw is supposed to be default I ended the code with format; but the error re: datalines stops the rest of the code so I don't know where to go from there.  I have used all the suggestions and reworked them in several ways but no go. As it's a 192 row SAS7bdat file I can't use datalines

Comment: If you have sas7bdat file you do not need either DATALINES or INPUT.  I suggest starting a new SAS session and a clean program.  Make sure you can actually see the dataset. Use it with something else.  For example run `PROC CONTENTS data=proj4.gasQTR;run;` to see what variables it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`in`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/n17vpypuojeg9zn1psc26z2ymju5.htm) operator or repeat the equality for every case.

Example from the [`doc`](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/z0780367.htm):

> You can use the IN operator with character strings to determine whether a variable's value is among a list of character values. The following statements produce the same results:
>
> - if state in ('NY','NJ','PA') then region+1;
> - if state='NY' or state='NJ' or state='PA' then region+1;

Therefore

```
DATA proj4.gasQTR;
   SET proj4.gasQTR;
   IF MONTH = 1 or MONTH = 2 or MONTH = 3 THEN Q1 = 1;
   ELSE IF MONTH = 4 or MONTH = 5 or MONTH = 6 THEN  Q2 = 2;
   ELSE IF MONTH = 7 or MONTH = 8 or MONTH = 9 THEN Q3 = 3;
   ELSE IF MONTH = 10 or MONTH = 11 or MONTH = 12 THEN Q4 = 4;   
   quarter = MONTH; FORMAT Quarter qtrw.;
RUN;
```

is equivalent to

```
DATA proj4.gasQTR;
   SET proj4.gasQTR;
   IF MONTH in (1,2,3) THEN Q1 = 1;
   ELSE IF MONTH in (4,5,6) THEN  Q2 = 2;
   ELSE IF MONTH in (7,8,9) THEN Q3 = 3;
   ELSE IF MONTH in (10,11,12) THEN Q4 = 4;   
   quarter = MONTH; FORMAT Quarter qtrw.;
RUN;
```

Comment: You cannot have an INPUT statement without either an INFILE statement or DATALINES (aka CARDS).

Comment: DATA proj4.gas;
         SET proj4.gas;
      IF MONTH in (1,2,3) THEN Q1 = 1;
    ELSE IF MONTH in (4,5,6) THEN  Q2 = 2;
    ELSE IF MONTH in (7,8,9) THEN Q3 = 3;
    ELSE IF MONTH in (10,11,12) THEN Q4 = 4;   
     quarter = MONTH; FORMAT _all_;
RUN;     *this basically worked but i have values missing where the qtr(1-4) isn't in the data set of course and i just realized you had responded so i apologize for seeing it earlier

Comment: DATA proj4.gas;
        SET proj4.gas;
        IF MONTH in (1,2,3) THEN Q1 = 1;
        ELSE IF MONTH in (4,5,6) THEN  Q2 = 2;
        ELSE IF MONTH in (7,8,9) THEN Q3 = 3;
        ELSE IF MONTH in (10,11,12) THEN Q4 = 4;   
         quarter = MONTH; FORMAT _all_;
    RUN;                                                                                                                                                            
    *this worked but i have values missing where the qtr(1-4) isn't in the data set of 
    course & sorry - i just saw your explanation - ThankYou4YourHelp!